# How to get all pages data from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get Facebook pages data from the whole Facebook , not only in my account. The only information I need which is the pages name, address, web page and phone number. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't search for an empty string, but you should get most pages if you do this:

- https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&fields=id,name,phone,website&q=a
- https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&fields=id,name,phone,website&q=b
- https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&fields=id,name,phone,website&q=c
- ...and so on

You'll have to remove the duplicates yourself.
I sure hope you won't be using this for spamming page owners.

Comment: So How Can I save the records to a database?

Comment: Also in the q= query , can I set the category type to Local business?Thanks A lot.